# Converting sequece of code into a function

Tags: number-theory, project-euler

I constructed a pretty basic sieve of Eratosthenes and would like to use it as a function rather than copy pasting output, how do I achieve

```
n = 5000000;
start = UnixTime[];
bsclst = Complement[Union[Range[3, n, 2], {2}], Range[9, n, 3]];
For[i = 3, i < Length[bsclst], i++, 
  If[bsclst[[i]] > Sqrt[n], Break[]]; 
  bsclst = 
    Complement[bsclst, Array[#*bsclst[[i]] &, IntegerPart[n/bsclst[[i]]] - 1, 2]]]
Total[bsclst]
stop = UnixTime[];
Print["Finding Primes up to ", n, " took ", stop - start, " Seconds"]
```

> ```
> 838596693108
> ```

```
Finding Primes up to 5000000 took 7 Seconds
```

All this does is take a number $n$ and return list/sum of primes up to $n$

Is there a general way to convert a sequence of top-level computations to function or would each case be done differently?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you search the documentation?
 Did you google?
  Please read the first two sections: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndProgramsOverview.html

Comment: @Szabolcs Second Section helped, thank you. Couldnt find this in offline documentation as my wordings were a bit ...Ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

```
func[n_] := Module[{},
  start = UnixTime[];
  bsclst = Complement[Union[Range[3, n, 2], {2}], Range[9, n, 3]];
  For[i = 3, i < Length[bsclst], i++, 
    If[bsclst[[i]] > Sqrt[n], Break[]];
    bsclst = 
     Complement[bsclst, 
      Array[#*bsclst[[i]] &, IntegerPart[n/bsclst[[i]]] - 1, 2]]]
   Total[bsclst]
   stop = UnixTime[];
  Print["Finding Primes up to ", n, " took ", stop - start, 
   " Seconds"]]
```

Output:

```
func[5000000]
```

> Finding Primes up to 5000000 took 4 Seconds

You can get the output as vector like this:

```
func[n_] := Module[{},
  start = UnixTime[];
  bsclst = Complement[Union[Range[3, n, 2], {2}], Range[9, n, 3]];
  For[i = 3, i < Length[bsclst], i++, 
   If[bsclst[[i]] > Sqrt[n], Break[]];
   bsclst = 
    Complement[bsclst, 
     Array[#*bsclst[[i]] &, IntegerPart[n/bsclst[[i]]] - 1, 2]]];
   stop = UnixTime[];
  {Total[bsclst],stop - start}
  ]
```

output:

```
func[5000000]
```

> {838596693108, 4}

But maybe you want the timing not just rounded to seconds then use Timing[], around the function, or allready as part of the definition like

```
func[n_] := Module[{},
  Timing[
   bsclst = Complement[Union[Range[3, n, 2], {2}], Range[9, n, 3]];
   For[i = 3, i < Length[bsclst], i++, 
    If[bsclst[[i]] > Sqrt[n], Break[]];
    bsclst = 
     Complement[bsclst, 
      Array[#*bsclst[[i]] &, IntegerPart[n/bsclst[[i]]] - 1, 2]]];
    stop = UnixTime[];
   Total[bsclst]
   ]
  ]
```

with

```
func[500000]
```

Output:

> {0.149548, 9914236195}

Comment: It doesnt output Total[bsclst]? Moreover, can i return the list (bsclst). Sorry im not very familiar with Mathematica, only done python so far

Comment: Nvm, found it, just use Return[] instead of Print[]. Whats the difference between using Module[] and using just parentheses around the block?

Comment: @AnvitGarg parentheses is totally fine. Module allows you to scope variables if you want that.